# c# mongo FindOne slow

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance

Sometimes, a FindOne takes more than a second => "_keywordRepo.GetKeyword   1034 ms". Here is an exemple for production code.

Here is the code from the DAL : KeywordRepository :

```
public async Task<Keyword> GetKeyword(string keywordName)
{
    return await MongoClientWrapper.FindOne<Keyword>(k => k.KeywordName == keywordName).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

MongoClientWrapper :

```
public static async Task<T> FindOne<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> memberExpression, FindOptions<T> findOptions = null)
{
    var coll = GetCollection<T>();
    if (findOptions == null)
        findOptions = new FindOptions<T>();

    findOptions.Limit = 1;
    IAsyncCursor<T> task = await coll.FindAsync(memberExpression, findOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await task.FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

There is indeed an index on "KeywordName" in mongo.
Is there something wrong ?

Comment: Could you run [cursor.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) and post the output ?

Comment: You should cache the client, database and collection fileds from your `GetCollection`. Then check mixed blocking and async code. Even though `continueOnCapturedContext: false` code might still run in the original sync context if search completes before being awaited.